# Google sheets: Does `iferror` evaluate the second argument if the first is not an error?

Tags: google-sheets

The title says it all...

Does `iferror` evaluate the second argument if the first is not an error?

Comment: And more generally, is there a way to keep a formula from evaluating to save on computation time?

Comment: Why would it? Google is smart which to optimize things here and there. You can trust that.

Comment: This seems easy enough to test. Have you tried it?